# passing values from view to controller to another view in codeigniter

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter-2, variable-assignment

I am trying to pass a value from a view to a controller then to a view, which does not work for a reason, here is my view link that passing the value

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('social_controller/load_modal/'.$row->PageFbPageID.''); ?>">More</a>
```

Here is my controller

```
function load_modal() {
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $term = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $this->load->view('/modals/fetch_modal',$term);


        }
```

and here is my `fetch_modal` view

```
<? 
echo $term;
?>
```

when i click More, the link actually has the value i need in the uri but i can not seem to pass it to the controller and then to my view , i am getting a white page only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you first assign it in an array like this:

```
$data['term'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

and then pass it like this:

```
$this->load->view('/modals/fetch_modal',$data);
```

and in your view you access it like this:

```
<? 
echo $term;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the $term variable in an array and then give it a key. That key will be the name of the variable into your view file.

```
//controller 
$this->load->view('/modals/fetch_modal',array('uri_term'=>$term));

//view 
var_dump($uri_term);
```